# Margins in booklet using \includepdf

Tags: margins, pdfpages, booklet

I have PDF that I am printing as a booklet using the following code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,booklet,turn=false,landscape]{doc.pdf}
\end{document}
```

How can I increase the inner margins of so that I can bind it properly?

Comment: `\usepackage[lmargin=2cm,tmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm]{geometry}` perhaps?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer But I want to change just the inner margin (which is left or right depending on the page)

Comment: `pdfpages` has options for this. I'm not sure whether `geometry` will work in this case. (Perhaps it will.)

Answer (score 1):

As @Christian Hupfer suggested, you should pass the margin options to `geometry` package. Specifically, setting `inner` should do the trick. To quote from its documentation:

> If margins on verso pages are swapped by `twoside` option, margins specified by `left` and `right` options are used for the inside and outside margins respectively. `inner` and `outer` are aliases of `left` and `right` respectively.